# Amazon SNS Mobile Push - How to send/publish to multiple endpoints?

Tags: php, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send messages to multiple users/Endpoints ARN selecting from MYSQL database without using Topic using PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Mobile Push can send notifications in two ways:

- Push a message to a single end-point
- Send a message to an Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) topic, and that topic pushes to multiple **subscribed** endpoints.

To send messages to multiple users/endpoints from a MySQL database, you would need an application that reads from the database, determines what message to send to whom, and then send that individual message to one endpoint. **To send to multiple users, use an SNS topic.**

See: [Amazon SNS Mobile Push Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately - SNS allows publishing to multiple endpoints using topic. So you'll have to use that. Keep in mind though for the topic subscription will only work one call at a time for each end-point. It does not have bulk subscription to topic feature yet:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=639931&#639931

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Mobile Push can send notifications in two ways :

1. Push notifications for a single device with Application single end- point ARN
2. Send a message to SNS topic and that topic pushed to all subscribed endpoint devices

So, better to use SNS Topic if you need to broadcast same message to multiple users device or, there is a other way to do it by using end-point ARN also. Simple you need to maintain all users information in your database and just trigger message by fetching all members from database and push message one by one to all members.

EG :

```
$users = all users information having user info and ARN 
        registered with SNS applications ARN;

foreach ($users as $user) {
   //Call AWS SNS pushed code with user's end-point informations, It will 
   //automatically send all subscribed users in present in your database 
  //tables also with proper informations
}
```